# The Android App regularly forgets my votes after I cast them, especially after commenting

Tags: bug, down-votes, android-app, up-votes

There's a curious bug that keeps tripping me up on the Android app: votes sometimes appear to revert in the client, though they stick successfully server side. I'm using app version 1.0.54 on Android 4.4.3.

I've found a couple of ways this happens:

- I'll give a post an up/downvote, the vote arrow will light up and the score will adjust. About a second later, enough time for a server ping and reply, the score will revert and the vote arrow will become unlit. This one happens **sometimes.** It's been happening for a while, but I'm not sure what version it started.
- I'll vote, and then leave a comment. When I leave the comment, my vote will revert: arrow becomes unlit, score reverts. This one happens **every time.** I am pretty sure it emerged just now in this version, 1.0.54.

In either case, if I attempt to re-cast my vote, the app will give me an error saying I've already voted on this answer and can't vote again. If I refresh, I see my vote has stuck, with the arrow lit and score adjusted accordingly. So the votes *definitely* get cast and stick server side, but the client side goes back to a state before they happened.

This one trips me up all the time: I'll vote, take some action (comment or read or scroll), then think "I thought I voted for that", try again, and get the error.

I suspect it might have something to do with reloading the posts in question from some kind of internal cache after a server reply, and the cached version doesn't have my vote recorded.

Comment: I think I've been seeing #2 for a little bit, but I confirm the behavior you describe, otherwise. About to watch my plussie seem to disappear...

Comment: Most likely too aggressive cache, as always.